# Considering the differential exact sequence $I/I^2\to\Omega_{S/R}\otimes_S S'\to\Omega_{S'/R}\to0$ as a chain of $S'$-modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Fix two rings maps $R\xrightarrow{\alpha}S\xrightarrow{\varphi}S'$, let $R\xrightarrow{\beta}S'$ be their composition, and suppose $\varphi$ is surjective with $I=\ker\varphi$. Then Lemma 10.130.9 of the Stacks project claims that we obtain an exact sequence of $S'$-modules $$I/I^2\to\Omega_{S/R}\otimes_S S'\to\Omega_{S'/R}\to 0$$ however, I don't see how $I/I^2$ can be considered as an $S'$-module.

Comment: Notice that $S'\cong S/I$ and $I/I^2$ is an $S/I$ module.

Comment: Is this considered an extension of scalars?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi:R\to S$ be any surjective map of rings, with $I=\ker\varphi$, then we give $I/I^2$ a natural $S$-module structure as follows: For $\overline{x}\in I/I^2$, and $\varphi(r)\in S$, we set $\varphi(r)\overline{x} = \overline{rx}$, and note that $\varphi(r)=0$ implies that $r\in I$, so that $\overline{rx}=0$, so this is well-defined.